# Default schema is ignored on SELECT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, schema

According to my understanding, a default schema should apply when 
issuing SQL statements on tables using unqualified table names.

My problem is that the following statement fails, because the table name
cannot be resolved.

```
-- Table name : [mydb].[myschema].[mytable]
USE mydb
SELECT * FROM mytable

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'mytable'.
```

I have a database user defined based on a Windows login user `mydomain\myuser` with the following properties:

- The login user is **not** a member of the `sysadmin` group, but only of `serveradmin` and `public`. According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx), these memberships should not be a problem.
- The mapped database user (also called `mydomain\myuser`) has the default schema `myschema` assigned.
- The database user is member of `db_owner`.

When connecting with MS SQL Management Studio as `mydomain\myuser`, calling `SCHEMA_NAME()` returns `dbo`. This indicates that for some reason, the default schema `myschema` is ignored. This is consistent with the failed SELECT statement.

But why is the default schema ignored?

Answer (score 4):

This [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095.aspx) gave me the hint:

> It is important note that if the user is authenticated by SQL Server as a member of a group in the Windows operating system, no default schema will be associated with the user.

My user `myuser` was a member of the Windows `Administrators` group **and**
there was an SQL Server login defined for the `Administrators` group.

After removing the user from this group, everything works fine.

I've read this documentation before, but skipped the crucial paragraph.